# Manipulating Strings in PHP with Functions

Tags: php, string

I searched every single str_replace, preg_replace, substr on StackOverflow and can't wrap my head around this.

The strings in my data are as such: "010758-01-700" or "860862-L-714". These are just examples.

These strings are 's

Instance 1:

> 010758-01-700
>   /ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=010758&config=01&format=l&imagenumber=1

If you look carefully at the URL and the string above it, I need to split this as "01075&config=01" and drop "-700" from the string to return a value I can insert into the URL

Instance 2:

> 860862-L-714
>   /ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=870078&color=001&format=l&imagenumber=1

I need to split this as "860862&&color=714" and drop all instances of "-XXS-, -XS-, -S-, -M-, -L-, -XL- ,-XXL-" for the string to return a value I can insert into the URL

There are strings that look like this throughout the data, 860862-L-714, 860862-M-999, 860862-XS-744. These are variations of product with the same name but different

I have tried `str_replace("-", "&config=", {ItemNo[1]})` but it returns 010758&config=01&config=700

I'd need to contain this all into a function that I can call into the URL

```
myFunction({ItemNo[1]})
```

Then I can setup the URL as so /ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=

```
myFunction({ItemNo[1]})&format=l&imagenumber=1
```

and if my logic is correct, it should work. I'm using WP All Import to import XML data.

How do I create a function that will manipulate the string  based on both instances above and output the results I'm trying to achieve?

Ok - based on the responses, I've solved the first instance to get the correct url to display - $content being the ItemNo

```
<?php
function ItemNoPart1 ( $content ) {
$content1 = explode("-", $content);
return $content1[0];    
}

function ItemNoPart2 ( $content ) {
$content2 = explode("-", $content);
return $content2[1];    
}   
?>

/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid=[ItemNoPart1({ItemNo[1]})]&config=[ItemNoPart2({ItemNo[1]})]&format=l&imagenumber=1
```

Now I just need to figure out how to do part 2 and combine it all into 1 function.

Comment: Was there a question here somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified.

Comment: There's not enough cohesion in how you want these strings to be structured to make something dynamic. You'll need to be doing `conditionals` based on the parameters in the query. In any event, this can be accomplished by some mixture of: `explode()`, `parse_str()`, and `strpos()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `str_replace`, use `explode` instead:

```
$str = '010758-01-700';
$chunks = explode( '-', $str );
```

By this way, resulting `$chunks` is an array like this:

```
[0] => 010758
[1] => 01
[2] => 700
```

So, now you can format desired URL in this way:

```
$url = "/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid={$chunks[0]}&config={$chunks[1]}&format=l&imagenumber=1"
```

Your desired function is this:

```
function myFunction( $itemID )
{
    $chunks = explode( '-', $itemID );
    return "/ImageServices/image.ashx?itemid={$chunks[0]}&config={$chunks[1]}";
}
```

... but, really you want a function for this stuff?

---

- Read more about [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to fiddle with this to see if I can get the result I'm looking for. I have it figured out in my head, I just need to figure it out in code :S

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand arrays more now.
    <?php
$str = "010758-01-700";
$chunks = explode( "-", $str );
echo '<pre>'; print_r($chunks); echo '</pre>';
?>
This help me understand the output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some psuedo code that may lead you in the right direction. The idea is to build out an array that contains **all** of the possible pieces of data from our string.

I've used a given constant of `/ImageServices/image.ashx?` to split upon, as we know the URL of our endpoint.

```
// explode our string into multiple parts
$parts = explode('/ImageServices/image.ashx?', $str);

// we know that the string we need to parse as at the index of 1
parse_str($parts[1], $parsed);

//$wanted will contain all of the data we can possibly need.
$wanted = array($parts[0], $parsed);
```

This will yield an array that looks like the following:

```
array (
    0 => '860862-L-714 ',
    1 => 
        array (
           'itemid' => '870078',
           'color' => '001',
           'format' => 'l',
           'imagenumber' => '1',
    ),
)
```

Now you can perform your conditionals such as when you need to look for `color` and create a specific URL structure:

```
if(array_key_exists('color', $wanted[1]){
    //create our custom sting structure here.
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Looks like I need to research on how arrays work. Thanks for the direction! I'll be back.